# Are questions on energy consumption on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I have asked [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/77696/27002) question on how LCD/LED size influences energy consumption in mobile devices. I was very doubtful, if this question is on topic, and thus placed a lot of explanation in end paragraph.

I have received certain number of upvotes, three great answers and a comment, that this question is valid for this side.

Being "armed" with such arguments, I have asked [a very similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/198095/27002) on how WiFi being enabled or not influences energy consumption in mobile devices.

Question was closed as off-topic, then attempted to be migrated to Super User, where migration was rejected and SU's question again closed as off-topic.

**What am I missing? How can question on correlation between LCD/LED size and energy consumption be on-topic, while similar question, on corerelation between WiFi and energy consumption (both questions in context of mobile devices) be off-topic?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree with Nick on this one. Your first question was a very generic question relating LCD display resolution to power consumption — an important *engineering* question for anyone in the business of designing such systems, and very much on-topic for this site.

Your second question related strictly to the use of a particular device, not its design, and is indeed off-topic here.

Comment: OK, I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

Your recent question is about electronics use.  Your 2013 question is about comparison of two consumer products.  Neither is about designing electronics.  All devices in question are designed, mass produced, and well on the market.

**edit:**
[The 2013 question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77696/does-higher-resolution-of-lcd-led-display-mean-higher-energy-consumption-for-the) had an engineering-sounding title, nevertheless it's a consumer question.  The O.P. is not designing electronics, is he?  It was overlooked and didn't get migrated to SuperUser.
Then it got into hot network questions.  The "hotness" is determined as a function of popularity rather than quality.  That's why it got a disproportionate amount of upvotes.

Comment: Either I'm missing something, or this should be a comment at most, not an answer. I was not asking you (or others) to repeat statements, that I already know, but to explain me the difference between this two questions, which are quite similar to me and yet, one received positive response while second was closed. With this answer, which clearly states, that both questions are similar (which I already know), you only make my confusion deeper. If they're so similar ("_Neither is about designing electronics_"), then why the were treated so differently?